# How do I only print the integers after a decimal point in C

Tags: c

This is my output now

```
cost = 12.88;
printf("Cost: %.0lf dollars and %.2lf cents", cost, cost-floor(cost));
```

//output

```
12 dollars and 0.88 cents
```

---

I need my output to look something like this

```
cost = 12.88
printf("%d Dollars and %d cents", cost)
```

output

```
12 dollars and 88 cents
```

Comment: Cents = Dollars * 100?

Comment: Multiply `cost-floor(cost)` by `100`. You should also round it because floating point is approximate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract fractional part of double \*efficiently\* in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589383/extract-fractional-part-of-double-efficiently-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void print_cost(double cost)
{
    double int_part;
    double fract_part = modf(cost, &int_part);
    printf(
        "%d Dollars and %d cents", //"%d" based on your example
        (int) int_part, //we must therefore cast to integer
        abs((int)(fract_part * 100.0)) //fract is signed, abs value needed
    );
}

int main()
{
    print_cost(12.88);
    print_cost(-12.88);
    print_cost(12.8899);
    return 0;
}
```

**Reference:**

- [abs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs)
- [modf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/modf)